# C# getting unusable base64 when converting from bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, string, bitmap, base64

I'm trying to capture the screen and then output the screenshot as a `base64` image but cannot seem to get a usable `base64` image out my code.

```
public static Bitmap bitmap;
    public static string base64;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureScreen();
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        richTextBox1.Text = base64;
    }
    public static string CaptureScreen()
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Bitmap bImage = bitmap;
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
        return base64;
    }
```

I get [this](https://pastebin.com/dqHKWhwX) output when testing and it should display this or close too [this](http://devknight.co.uk/view?i=154) image.

Comment: You're copying 0 width and 0 height...?

Comment: do u mean on graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size); this is just for displaying what the result should look like. just for development

Comment: but: you're allocating an empty bitmap, writing nothing to it, then saving it; you should expect to see a black (or white) rectangle. What do you see? it looks like a black rectangle to me...

Comment: when i convert the base64 string back into an image i get a black square. i get a full working screenshot displayed in the picturebox1

Comment: what did you expect, and why? why would you expect to see anything *else*? You allocated an empty bitmap, and wrote nothing to it...

Comment: how can i fix this though. im quite new to c#.

Comment: oh, I see; one sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is timing.

You are creating the base-64 **before** you copy the screen into the image; you need to move the line:

```
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
```

to happen **before** the line:

```
bImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Try literally just changing it to:

```
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bImage.Size);
bImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Thank You very much Marc! :D

Comment: I have searched this question, and in my case I have updated with the line `bImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);` the format, I have used `.Bmp`, changed to `.Jpeg` and reached the desired output